# How flexible is the suffix -ee?

Tags: suffixes, er-ee

I have read some posts about the suffix *-ee,* which is added to a verb to turn it into a word that describes a person having the action done to them: e.g. *employ* becomes *employee*, a person who is employed. I may have missed a question or thread, but I could not find anything that describes the limits of what *-ee* can be attached to.

I know that the verb has to be transitive, and the subject must be alive, but that is all.

Comment: These usually come in pairs employer/employee, And if an actor type word ends in -er (a person who does something to someone), then it is easy to make up a new word replacing -er- with -ee meaning, the person done _to_. But what about divorcee, fiancee, soiree, etoufee, marquee, banshee?

Comment: Warning:  There are people who dislike -ee words.  A word like employee has been around long enough to become OK, but askee, asylee?   After only the "a" list from the answer of @Max Williams I felt a strong urge to barf.  +1 for his answer but minus infinity for some of the words on the list he referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not** a rule of English grammar that you can add *-ee* to any verb to describe the subject.

It should be seen more as a common approach to creating a new word.  Like any new word, or neologism, the resulting word still needs to be accepted by the community: many new words fail and die because people just don't like them.

You will find that in some cases, people can guess the meaning of your new *-ee* word, and accept it.  In other cases, they might be confused or just dislike it.  Many people might be resistant to the whole idea of inventing new *-ee* words and find the word "distasteful" for that reason.

The *-ee* words you could think of, like "employee", are neologisms that have gone through the "acceptance process".

Either way, it's a new word that you've created, rather than a product of standard grammar, and you should bear that in mind.  If you were writing something formal, you would not normally include **any** neologisms - they are more well suited to something more light-hearted.

EDIT:  the following page lists the *-ee* suffix words which have entered the language to date.  More may enter in the future.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ee

Comment: Can you give some example words that show where it is possible and where not?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-ee

Comment: Note that this isn't a list of what is **possible**, it's a list of accepted words created with this process.  There might be lots of others which will enter the language in the future (and therefore are "possible").

Comment: Can you add a couple of those to you answer to make your answer complete by itself? And also give an acceptable neologism (one not on that list)?

Comment: I've added the link, I don't see the value of picking some examples from that page and reproducing them in my answer.

Comment: I also don't see the point of me making up a new word and adding that to my answer.  I've answered your question as it stands.

Comment: I'm just giving you pointers on how to make a good self-contained answer. You've given a great explanation, but it would be aided by having examples directly in your answer.

Comment: I think the answer should reflect the question, which doesn't ask for examples of words with the -ee suffix.  It doesn't actually ask **any** question, on further inspection, but the **implied** question is about the rules for what can be suffixed with -ee, and this is what I have addressed.  Feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: You bring up a good point about the "acceptance process" of neologisms! Thank you, my question has been answered and I've learned something extra in the process. I wanted to use "injuree" to refer to a person with an injury, and I was wondering about whether or not it would be appropriate. I will keep your tip about the difference between formal and casual usage of neologisms.

Comment: "Injuree" is a particularly bad example, because a) it sounds like "injury" and so will cause confusion, and b) there's already a phrase for this which is "the injured party".